# ngx-admin + ng-dynamic-forms: 'dynamic-bootstrap-form' is not a known element

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

so, I want to implement Dynamic Forms on my project, that is using ngx-Admin (Nebular), but I keep getting `'dynamic-bootstrap-form' is not a known element`, even if it is packaged on the `vendor.bundle.js`... I tried with both Angular 5 and 4 versions, to see if there was something wrong, and since I can't figure out what, I come here to ask for some help.

Some relevant files:
**app.module.ts**

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {CoreModule} from './@core/core.module';

// Custom form builder
import {DynamicFormsCoreModule} from '@ng-dynamic-forms/core';
import {DynamicFormsBootstrapUIModule} from '@ng-dynamic-forms/ui-bootstrap';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {ThemeModule} from './@theme/theme.module';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NB_AUTH_TOKEN_WRAPPER_TOKEN, NbAuthJWTToken} from '@nebular/auth';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth-guard.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

        DynamicFormsCoreModule.forRoot(),
        DynamicFormsBootstrapUIModule,

        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ThemeModule.forRoot(),
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        {provide: NB_AUTH_TOKEN_WRAPPER_TOKEN, useClass: NbAuthJWTToken},
        AuthGuard,
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**user-form.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import {
    DynamicFormArrayModel,
    DynamicFormControlModel,
    DynamicFormService,
    DynamicInputModel,
} from '@ng-dynamic-forms/core';
import { USER_FORM_MODEL } from '../../../forms/user/user-form.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-user-form',
    templateUrl: './cadastro-usuario.component.html',
})
export class CadastroUsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
    formModel: DynamicFormControlModel[] = USER_FORM_MODEL;
    formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formService: DynamicFormService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.formService.createFormGroup(this.formModel);
    }
}
```

**user-form.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nb-card>
            <nb-card-header>User Form</nb-card-header>
            <nb-card-body>
                <form [formGroup]="formGroup">

                    <dynamic-bootstrap-form [group]="formGroup"
                                            [model]="formModel"></dynamic-bootstrap-form>

                </form>
            </nb-card-body>
        </nb-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

**user-form.model.ts**

```
import {
    DynamicFormControlModel,
    DynamicCheckboxModel,
    DynamicInputModel,
    DynamicRadioGroupModel,
    DynamicFormGroupModel,
} from '@ng-dynamic-forms/core';

export const USER_FORM_MODEL: DynamicFormControlModel[] = [

    new DynamicInputModel({
        id: 'user-name',
        label: 'Full Name',
        validators: {
            required: true,
            minLenght: 10,
        },
    }),

];
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test -sr",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- -cc",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
    "deploy": "./deploy.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "@asymmetrik/angular2-leaflet": "2.1.4",
    "@nebular/auth": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@nebular/theme": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/core": "^1.4.34",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/ui-bootstrap": "^1.4.34",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "5.2.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.3.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "d3": "4.8.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "leaflet": "1.0.3",
    "nebular-icons": "1.0.6",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ngx-echarts": "1.2.2",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.4.6",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.1",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.0.60",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must import 'dynamic-bootstrap-form' module into your theme.module.ts from  `src/app/@theme` folder.